# Electronic urn pumps

Tags: power-supply, mechanical, water, fluid-pump

How exactly do electronic auto dispensers/pumps, such as [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00XIMQIQM), work? What are the mechanics behind it?

(I'd appreciate any information provided, even if it's a comment.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about pump mechanics, not electronics design. Maybe engineering.SE would be a better place to ask, but please read their rules before posting there!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Even though the company markets the product specifically as an electric dispenser?

Comment: indeed. There is not much electronic about the question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well then, if there isn't much electric mechanics *that* can be an answer. Very possible the marketing specs. are inaccurate.

Comment: No! your question is "how does this pump work", and even if the pump has an electric motor inside, a pump is a mechanical engineering problem. Not an electrical engineering one. Or maybe I misunderstand both your question and the tags you used.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I may have not phrased the question well; apologies. The pump is, apparently, electronically facilitated. The q is how does the electrical engineering in this device activate the pump? If this is still off topic i have no problem deleting the q.

Comment: probably an air pump

Comment: @Oliver presumably by applying power to the motor which causes part of the pump to rotate

Comment: You should post a question on Amazon. Likely only an owner of one of these would have figured out how it works.

Comment: @jsotola Thats what I assumed but it's explicitly advertised as an electric pump. Unless you also think the product isn't accurately described.

Comment: @CharlesCowie That's a good idea, thanks. FWIW, I searched similar products (with dual pumps; air and auto/electric) on the web and even manufacturers don't explain the electric element.

Comment: @Oliver I'm guessing from your network profile that this is related to whether the urn may be used on Shabbat. If so, edit the question to explain that context. That would probably actually make it on-topic for EE.SE!

Comment: @pericynthion That's a sensible guess, Sherlock, though I don't see how that detail would change the substance of the q. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @pericynthion: Why would that change the context? And pardon my ignorance - why should you not use a dispenser urn on the Shabbat?

Comment: @MrGerber I too don't know how it would change the context on make this on-topic. For your general knowledge, [here's](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1159378/jewish/Electricity-on-Shabbat.htm) a basic survey re. the Shabbat issue.

Answer (score 1):

the urn probably has an electric air pump (compressor)

here is a rough diagram

raising air pressure above the liquid causes the liquid to be pushed up and out of the tube

[image]

Comment: How would the compressor be electronically activated?

Comment: What do you know about how electrical energy can be turned into mechanical energy?

Comment: @Oliver, the control circuit would have an electronic (or mechanical) switch that would make a connection between the power supply (battery) and the pump motor. .... it is actually unclear what you are asking.